# Rails one_to_many Association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, slack-api

I am trying to model one to many relationship in rails with an example of user and team.

In my example, user can have only one team and team can have multiple users. user contains team_id field

Schema:

```
  create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "slack_team_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.boolean "active", default: true
    t.string "domain"
    t.string "token"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "bot_user_id"
    t.string "activated_user_id"
    t.string "activated_user_access_token"
    t.string "question_time", default: "10:00", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "user_name"
    t.string "nickname"
    t.string "slack_user_id"
    t.bigint "team_id"
    t.index ["team_id"], name: "index_users_on_team_id"
  end

add_foreign_key "users", "teams"
```

Team model:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
end
```

EDIT:
What is not working?
=> When I try to do `team.users`, it says NoMethodError for users function.

I believe that its because I am using Slack Ruby bot gem(https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-bot-server)

Here the Team model is already specified: https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-bot-server/blob/master/lib/slack-ruby-bot-server/models/team/methods.rb

I feel It is using this Team model and not the team model that I have created.
Any pointers as to how I can say that it should use my own Team model.

EDIT 2=>

How I am accessing team.users?
The slack-ruby-bot gem provides with functionality to extend a slack command and it will give a callback when that command is typed by user.

Here I am using it as:

```
class Give < SlackRubyBot::Commands::Base
  def self.call(client, data, match)
   team = client.owner
   puts team.users
  end
end
```

As you can see, team is returned by the slack-ruby-bot's internal implementation.

Please help me understand why this is not working

Comment: what is not working? what issue are you facing?

Comment: @Nandhini edited to give more context on whats not working

Comment: From the code that you've provided, an instance of the Team class will respond to `users`. Your problem here is that you're not calling `users` on what you think you're calling it on. Can you provide the part of code where you call `team.users`? As `team` there will not be an instance of the team  class.

Comment: been a while, but what if you do `Team.new.users` .  or `Team.all[0].users` . or . `User.new.team`

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help's you.

In relation we can access data like below

`Team.all[0].users`

`Team.first.users`

`User.first.team`

`Team.all.map{|t| t.users}`